# How to only detect a swipe if its longer than 100 px LibGDX

Tags: android, libgdx

On my game screen i want to have a swipe detected only if its more than 100px, this is because the user taps a lot on the game screen and it tends to detect a swipe which changes the screen back to title. How can i make the swipe detect only if its longer than 100px?

Comment: No one wants to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the position in the touch up and down.

```
private Vector2 downPos = new Vector2(), upPos = new Vector2();
private Vector3 tmp = new Vector3();
public void touchDown(float x, float y.....) {
    tmp.set(x, y, 0);
    camera.unproject(tmp);
    downPos.set(tmp.x, tmp.y);
}

public void touchUp(float x, float y.....) {
    tmp.set(x, y, 0);
    camera.unproject(tmp);
    upPos.set(tmp.x, tmp.y);

    float distance = downPos.dst(upPos); // the distance between thoose vectors
    if (distance > 100) {
        // there was a swipe of a distance longer than 100 pixels.
    }
}
```

If you don't want to do that only on touch up, put the code in the touchdrag method.

Comment: I have just tried to implement the code but the problem is there is no `touchUp` method in my `GestureHandler` class that `implements GestureListener` how would i do it in there? Sorry for the bother!

Comment: Use InputProccesor. Gdx.input.setInputProccesor(new InputProccesor( .......................... ) ..

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve this.

The first one is to save the starting point of the touch and measure the distance on end of the touch event, just like Paul mentioned.

The second is to enlarge the tap square size if you use the GestureDetector of libgdx. Its defaulted to 40px which means if you're finger moves more than 20px to any side it's no longer a tap event but a pan event. I'd recommend using the GestureListener/Detector as it will give you the basic mobile gestures out of the box rather than recoding them.

On a side note: Determining the distance by pixels is error-prone because the pixel density will vary between mobile devices, especially if you code for android! 100px on one device may be only half the distance than on another device. Take pixel density into consideration when doing this or change to relative measurements like 1/3 of the screen size!